# How to execute multiple commands after opening a new terminal tab

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

I need to open a new terminal tab and execute multiple commands on it, how can I do it. I have already tried the following,

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t "X" -e "cd ~/Desktop/terminal_test;mkdir test"
```

Here I need to cd into a new directory and create a new folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "cmd1; cmd2; …cmdN; exec bash"
```

Comment: @ycrnet I modified it

Comment: Thanks alot, this works, 
The complete command would be

`gnome-terminal --tab -t "XXX"  -x bash -c "cd ~/Desktop/terminal_test; mkdir test; exec bash`

Answer (score 0):

You can use gnome-terminal. The script below will open 3 tabs running the respective commands..

```
tab="--tab"

cmd01="bash -c 'ls';'pwd';bash"

foo=""

foo+=($tab -e "$cmd01")

gnome-terminal "${foo[@]}"

exit 0
```